# Bash: Insert special characters text after string in text file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

Been looking at a lot of sed and awk code examples but still couldn't figure out my problem. Getting all sorts of syntax problems.

I got the following text file (notice the whole thing is actually on 1 single line):

```
<item><title>myTitle1</title><link>myLink1</link></item><item><title>myTitle2</title><link>myLink2</link></item> etc...
```

I need to insert: `<tag>myTag</tag>`
after each `</link>`.

End result should be:

```
<item><title>myTitle1</title><link>myLink1</link><tag>myTag</tag></item><item><title>myTitle2</title><link>myLink2</link><tag>myTag</tag></item> etc...
```

Any sed/awk gurus out there =P

Comment: Please post the code you tried

Comment: I tried:
    `awk '/<\/link>/ { print; print "<tag>myTag</tag>"; next }1' textfile.txt`
but that just inputs it at the end of the file.
I also tried with sed:


    `sed '/<\/link>/a <tag>myTag<\/tag>' textfile.txt`


and got the same result as awk.

Im' definitely doing something wrong here xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the prettiest way, but works here:

```
sed -i 's/<\/link>/<\/link><tag>myTag<\/tag>/g' example.xml
```

- `-i` stands for in place and replaces in the files instead just output
- the patters `'s/a/b/g'` searches (s) for `a` and replaces with `b`, where `g` stands for globally for all appearances, not just once
- `/` has to be escaped to `\/`

also beware trying too much regex on XML, that is going to hit hard

Answer (score 0):

Using awk you'd:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/<\/link>/,"&<tag>myTag</tag>")}1' file
<item><title>myTitle1</title><link>myLink1</link><tag>myTag</tag></item><item><title>myTitle2</title><link>myLink2</link><tag>myTag</tag></item> etc...
```